# Left Join Lento no Firebird 2.0

Tags: firebird, join

Tenho duas tabelas:

**Venda** > 100 Registros 
Campos chave primária: Fatura

**Pagamentos** > 200.000 Registros 
Campos chave primária: Id, Fatura, tipodevenda, documento.

Tenho o seguinte SQL:

```
Select V.FATURA, P.ID
  From Venda V
Left Join Pagamentos P on p.FATURA = V.FATURA
Where v.DTEMI between '25.09.2018' and '25.09.2018'
```

Porém ele está muito lento. O que eu posso fazer para melhorar a performance?

Comment: O campo `Fatura` da tabela `pagamentos` é chave estrangeira da tabela `venda`?? Coloque a estrutura das suas duas tabelas na pergunta para facilitar o entendimento!

Comment: Não, não tenho chave estrangeira ligando essas tabelas. É um sistema legado antigo. Como coloquei lá em cima a tabela Venda tem o campo chave primaria: fatura apenas. Já a tabela Pagamentos tem quatro campos chave primária. @MatheusRibeiro

Comment: A minha resposta lhe ajudou? Um feedback é sempre bem vindo!

Comment: Adicionei o index, mas não ví melhora. A chave estrangeira ajudou, mas não posso criar ela sem antes deletar os itens duplicados, isso fica inviável pra mim. Ainda não tive tempo de procurar outras soluções, mas qualquer coisa posto aqui

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso para melhorar a performance você terá duas opções

1ª Criar um index para sua tabela, com isso pode ser que melhore bem

```
CREATE INDEX VENDAS_IDX1 ON VENDAS (FATURA);
```

2ª Modificar a estrutura da sua tabela `pagamentos` para que o campo `pagamentos.fatura` seja uma chave estrangeira da tabela `vendas`.

O correto seria a 2ª opção, mas como você comentou que é um sistema legado você terá que ver se é viável mudar.